# C++ Runnable class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, dlopen

I'd like to achieve something similar to interface Runnable from Java. I try to do that in that way:

```
class Runnable{
    public:
        void start(){
            t = std::thread(&Runnable::run, this);
        }
    protected:
        virtual void run(){
        }
};
```

Idea is simple. I'd like to overload run method and then start() should launch overloaded one. But... it doesn't work.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Operation not permitted
```

PS I load an instance of class, which derives from Runnable, from dynamic library with dlopen.

Comment: Don't try to emulate Java in C++. Especially not the parts of Java which are inferior to C++. C++ doesn't need a "Runnable" class, because it has functors. Have your class overload `operator()()` instead of defining a `run` function, and then simply pass that to a new `std::thread`. Simpler, cleaner and more efficient

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still not familiar with C++11. I will investigate that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not specific to C++11. You've always had functors in C++. The only part that's new to C++11 is the `std::thread` class, which you already use. Anyway, I'll backtrack a bit: `std::thread` is an object which, instead of containing a "run" function, is *given* the function to run in its thread. This function can be represented by a function pointer, but it can also be a *functor*, which is simply an object which overloads the `operator()`. An object `x` which has this operator can be "called" just like a function can, with the syntax `x()`.

Comment: So this is a very natural way to express "the function I wish to run". Simply define a class which implements this operator, and then pass that object to a `std::thread`. This is both more flexible and maintainable than the Java approach (you don't need to subclass the `thread` class, and you can run *anything* that looks like a function in a separate thread. And it offers a better separation of concerns. You have one class whose responsibility it is to manage a thread, and another class which represents the task you wish the thread to perform

Comment: I used functors in C++, but I just started with std::thread and I didn't know that I can do this kind of magic. I used to pass static methods to pthreads. The constructor of class, which instance I will pass to std::thread, has to be public?

Comment: What @jalf said. But on top of that *this is not similar to the `Runnable` interface in Java*. This is similar to the `Thread` class.

Comment: The copy constructor has to be public (because the `std::thread` object has to create a copy of the functor. But other than that, there are no requirements

Comment: One more thing. It looks that std::thread always use operator() from the base class, even if it is virtual, why?

Comment: I recorded a tutorial that might be helpful. Google for "C++11 Concurrency Tutorial" on the Corensic web site. It gives examples of how to start and join threads. As others commented: Java runnable is not a good abstraction for C++. In Java everything has to be object, even if a free function makes more sense.

Comment: @jalf : The functor must be _movable_ in order to work with `std::thread`; there's no limitation that it must be copied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is commonly seen produced by GCC when forgetting to use `-pthread` at command line.

Comment: @MiniKarol: IIRC `std::thread` uses pthreads underneath on Linux. I don't know if this is the cause of the error, though.

Comment: @MiniKarol If you are using GCC 4.5+, you need `-lpthread` to use `std::thread`. If you're using something else, the question needs more details to be answerable.

Comment: After adding -lpthread to linker I received segmentation fault probably related to my virtual method run.

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem with your code: You are not allowed to call virtual functions from the constructor of the class. Doing so yields undefined behaviour.

Comment: I know that in constructor my object is not fully initialized, but I don't call any virtual method within it.

Comment: You pass a function pointer to a thread. This means the thread can call the virtual function before the constructor has finalized. Seems like adding bugs that are really difficult to track.